# How to check if the object is in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
[#<Merit::Badge id: 1, name: "just-registered", level: nil, description: nil, custom_fields: nil>,
 #<Merit::Badge id: 2, name: "change-username", level: nil, description: nil, custom_fields: nil>]
```

How can I check if for example badge id 2 is present in the array?

Comment: We can't answer it unless you tell us how to get the id of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have that model loaded in other object - just `array.include?(badge)`, if not - `array.any?{|b| b.id==2 }` (but do not hardcode the id)

Comment: Rails also provides an [`in?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F) method: `badge.in?(array)`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your array is `merits`, the solution should be:

```
merits.index { |obj| obj.id == 2 }.nil?
```

That line of code above check if the id of 2 NOT present in the array. Please [see here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) for more details on the API

Answer (score 0):

you can try for your `active record` model `Merit::Badge` .

```
Merit::Badge.exists?(badge.id)
```

For your case badge id 2

```
Merit::Badge.exists?(2)
```

For more on `exists?` you can refer: [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class)

Answer (score 0):

```
found_object = merge_barge_list.find{|merit_badge| merit_badge.id == 2}
if found_object
  # object found
else
  # object not found
end
```